# GetGeopositionAsync() never finishes, works pefect the second time it is called

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have used `GetGeoPositionAsync()` in my app and it works fine in the code of another feature, however when using it in the feature I am currently implementing, it freezes the first time I try to call it, and works the second time. I call this function when navigating from another page. Here's the code:

```
   private async Task GetLocation()
   {
        Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition myGeoposition = null;
        try
        {
            myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80004004)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unauthorized access.");
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried browsing SO, but haven't found a working solution for this. Why does it work in some pieces of code, and in some it just doesn't. What is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: If it works in one place but not another, start by looking at what's different between those two places. Where and how are you calling `GetLocation()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution:

```
        try
        {
            IAsyncOperation<Geoposition> locationTask = null;
            try
            {
                locationTask = myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                myGeoposition = await locationTask;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (locationTask != null)
                {
                    if (locationTask.Status == AsyncStatus.Started)
                        locationTask.Cancel();

                    locationTask.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Excellent solution. But i have one problem if i am using `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)` then it will show timeout error if set value grate than 3 then it will work. one more thing can i reduce time interval 3 second to 1 second. because in my application if i am setting value less than 4 then timeout error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the position is cached! The first time you call the method it tries to get your position (this can take many seconds if you are inside a building), the second time it seems to use the cached position.